# WPF + WebAPI, async Как корректно передать данные для приложения?

Tags: c#, json, mvvm, асинхронность, webapi

вопрос в следующем:Как корректно передать данные с серверной части, чтобы сделать привязку данных для клиентской?

**Серверная часть:**

getInfo_Employee.cs:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Коллекция сотрудников
    /// </summary>
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> employees;

    /// <summary>
    /// Заполнение коллекции из БД
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>заполненная коллекция из БД</returns>
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        string Query = "SELECT * FROM Employee";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Query, sqlConnection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    employees.Add(
                        new Employee()
                        {
                            Name = rd["Name"].ToString(),
                            SurName = rd["SurName"].ToString(),
                            Age = rd["Age"].ToString(),
                            Department = rd["Department"].ToString()
                        });
                }
            }
        }
        return employees;
    }
```

Есть готовая база данных(БД) и в серверной части создается коллекция на основе БД.

Контроллер Employee:

```
private Info_Employee emp = new Info_Employee();

    [Route("getemployees")]
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Get() => emp.GetEmployees();
```

**Клиентская часть: WPF + MVVM**

ViewModel:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58205/");
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    getCommands();
    var employees = Method();
}

public static async Task<ObservableCollection<Employee>> Method()
{
    return await GetEmployeesAsync(Client.BaseAddress + "getemployees");
}

public static async Task<ObservableCollection<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsync(string path)
{
    ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = null;
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.GetAsync(path);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            employees = await
            response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ObservableCollection<Employee>>();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return employees;
}
```

Пытаюсь в `var employees` передать полученную информацию с серверной части, но делаю что-то не так, потому что результат async метода `result = null`.

Как мне корректно передать данные с сервера, чтобы `View` я мог передать `DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();` и от него взять `ItemsSource ="{Binding Path = employees}"`

за малые знания `async` заранее извиняюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы дождаться окончания выполнения асинхронной операции и выполнить действия над результатом, используйте оператор `await`.

```
ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = await Method();
// ваш код
```

Работает это таким образом:

1. Метод Method запускает асинхронный запрос к веб сервису. Ответ от сервиса прийдет позднее.
2. `// ваш код` не выполняется сразу, а управление сразу переходит в предыдущий метод. Таким образом, на экране появится представление без данных.
3. Как только приходит ответ от веб сервиса, запускается `// ваш код`. Здесь необходимо полученный результат привязать к отображенному ранее представлению, и заставить его отобразить эти данные.